# Concatenating layers in Keras tensorflow2

Tags: python, keras, concatenation, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I am trying to concatenate layers in keras tensorflow2:

```
initialinputs = Input(shape = (500, 4),name="sequences")

conv1d1 = Conv1D(hyperparameters['conv1_hidden_units'],
                activation='relu',
                kernel_size=hyperparameters['conv1_filter_size'],
                input_shape=(500, 4),
                padding='same')(initialinputs)
maxpool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hyperparameters['maxpool1_width'])(conv1d1)
dropout1 = Dropout(0.1)(maxpool1)
conv1d2 = Conv1D(hyperparameters['conv2_hidden_units'],
                activation='relu',
                kernel_size=hyperparameters['conv2_filter_size'],
                input_shape=(500, 4),
                padding='same')(dropout1)
maxpool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hyperparameters['maxpool2_width'])(conv1d2)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.1)(maxpool2)
conv1d3 = Conv1D(hyperparameters['conv3_hidden_units'],
                activation='relu',
                kernel_size=hyperparameters['conv3_filter_size'],
                input_shape=(500, 4),
                padding='same')(dropout2)
maxpool3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hyperparameters['maxpool3_width'])(conv1d3)
dropout3 = Dropout(0.1)(maxpool3)
flatten = Flatten()(dropout3)

otherInp = Input(shape = (11,),name="coverage")
concatenatedFeatures = Concatenate(axis=1)([flatten, otherInp])

out = Dense(hyperparameters['num_classes'], activation='softmax')(concatenatedFeatures)

model = Model(inputs = [initialinputs, otherInp], outputs = out)
```

But I keep getting the error message:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected coverage to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I think there is something obvious I am missing here, I've had a search on StackOverflow already and can't seem to find the solution.  Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: The error just says the shape of your input is not the expected value (1 vs 11), hard to say why, can you explain why your input has shape (1,) instead of (11,)?

Comment: Or vice-versa.....

Comment: This is the part I don't understand, I thought because I specified  `otherInp = Input(shape = (11,),name="coverage") `  it would be the right shape.

Comment: The input file when running model.fit() for otherInp is shape (11,7570) if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrectly loaded the 'otherInp' so that it did have shape (1,), have changed this and it works fine.  Thanks for your help!